# Runtime warning plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, runtime, dask

When I tried to plot some data using the following line of code: `ndvi.mean(['x', 'y']).plot.line('b-^', figsize=(11,4))`

I got a lot of warning, like: [runtime warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SOyE.png)

Here is my config:

- Windows
- Python 3.9.15
- dask==2022.12.0
- Matplotlib==3.7.1
- Numpy==1.23.5

How can I solve it? I put my whole code below.
Thank you

It's a `xarray.Dataset` with chunks from:

```
nir = xr.concat([rioxarray.open_rasterio(i,chunks={'x':2048, 'y':2048},lock=True) for i in nirlist], dim=time_v) red = xr.concat([rioxarray.open_rasterio(i,chunks={'x':2048, 'y':2048},lock=True) for i in redlist], dim=time_v) scl..the same with xr.concat

ds=xr.merge([nir,red,scl],compat='no_conflicts', join='left')[xarray.Dataset example][1]
```

For example, I calculated ndvi of a zonal time series.

```
ndvi=(ds['nir']-ds['red'])/(ds['nir']+ds['red'])
```

When I tried to a plot `ndvi.mean(['x', 'y']).plot.line('b-^', figsize=(11,4))`

I obtained a list of warnings that I showed in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZykRN.png) at the end of this warnings I didn’t visualize the graph, it’s empty, only the axis. O for example when I use ndvi.load() or ndvi.compute() it happens the same a lot of warnings, but in this case it works, I could calculate after ndvi.argmax('time'))..

Comment: Please add a snippet of code and copy and paste the error message instead of screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I provided some code, thank you